# MacOS keeps asking for SMB password

Tags: mojave, keychain, smb

Whenever I (re-)mount a SMB share, Mojave prompts me for my credentials. I faithfully enter my data, hit the "store in keychain" checkbox ("Password im Schlüsselbund speichern" in German), and the share is successfully mounted. Next time, for example after a reboot, it will ask for the username+password again.

My username consists of a domain and login ("mydomain\MYUSER"). Interestingly, when the dialog box opens, it only displays "MYUSER" in the form field, without the domain, and I have to type in the domain.

In the Keychain app, I am seeing an entry for this share, where everything seems to be fine. The domain *is* included in the account name there.

How can I debug or investigate this more? Or is this a known issue?

EDIT: Deleting the entries from the key chain did not help.

EDIT2: I connected through a LAN instead of WIFI, and I believe it did not prompt me for a password. I'll have to test that again though...

Comment: Have you tried deleting the existing entr/y/ies in Keychain Access/Schlüsselbundverwaltung and recreating them? Can you check if there are multiple entries for the same server/share? I remember having multiple Keychain entries for the same server/share b/c of different mounting methods (Bonjour, CMD-K etc.)

Comment: I'll try that, @Gummibando

Comment: @AnoE Did that work for you? I've just run into the exact same issue and am searching for a solution.

Comment: See the edit, @luckman212 - no luck with deleting...

Comment: Deleting the existing entries worked for me.  I deleted all entries for the same server, where some were referring to the server by IP address and some were referring to the server by domain name.  After that, I mounted the drives using the command line, was prompted for the password once, and then no longer had to enter the password on subsequent mounts.